# Flag Friend (D7): add link in block

Tags: 7, blocks, navigation, flags

I have created a custom block (that resides with path visibility of `users/*`).

I have written some PHP code to allow users to message each other (D7 [Privatemsg](http://drupal.org/project/privatemsg) module):

```
<?php
// Get user object.
if ($account = menu_get_object('user')) {
  if ($url = privatemsg_get_link(array($account))) {
    return l(t('write a mail to this user'), $url, array(
      'query' => drupal_get_destination(),
    ));
  }
}
?>
```

In that same block, I would like to add another snippet to show a [Flag Friend](http://drupal.org/project/flag_friend) link. This would give me one block with two links: one for mail, one for adding/removing friendship.

Does anyone know the PHP code for flagging a friend?

Answer (score 1):

I think the method below should do the trick. Don't think it is available in the `flag_friend` module's API.

```
/**
 * Gets the friend/unfriend link for a given user.
 *
 * Depending on the flagging user's current friend status with the target
 * user, the label of this link will show up as 'Add friend' or 'Remove friend'.
 *
 * @param stdClass $account
 *   Target user object. Defaults to the currenly logged in user.
 *
 * @return mixed
 *   FALSE or 
 *   Formatted flag/unflag link otherwise.
 *
 * @see flag_friend_flag_default_flags().
 * @see flag_create_link().
 */
function flag_friend_get_friend_flag_link($account = NULL) {
  if (!isset($account)) {
    global $user;
    $account = $user;
  }
  return flag_create_link('friend', $account->uid);
}
```

Do note that the flagging user is assumed by default to be the currently logged in user which fits your use-case anyway.

Access check happens implicitly. So, if the current user does not have access to friend/unfriend a given target user, then this method will return `FALSE`.